# unmodifiable attribute in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, readonly

I have simply model class:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

I want to set attribute `title` **unmodifiable** in django admin. What should I do to set this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the field name to `readonly_fields` of that model's `ModelAdmin` class. According to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields):

> By default the admin shows all fields as editable. Any fields in this option (which should be a list or tuple) will display its data as-is and non-editable.

In your situation this looks like:

```
readonly_fields = ("title",)
```